# Trying to install Magento 2.4.1 using command line ? What is elasticsearch host?

Tags: magento2, installation, elasticsearch, cli

I got this example command from the guide (tutorial) - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html#install-cli-example

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I also have elasticsearch running. 
But I have a doubt that `host.example.com` should be something good value(I am trying to install magento on localhost ) is it correct or not, if i copy paste the above command and run..
This below line `elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com`  should be `elasticsearch-host=es-host.localhost.com`  . 
 I don't know if I am right or wrong, but please help me in proceeding further, any help will be great help.

Comment: My doubt - Elasticsearch 7 is installed on es-host.example.com and connects on port 9200       -   Should i change es-host.example.com to something else or use it as it is.

Comment: did you try without `--search-engine`, `--elasticsearch-host` & `--elasticsearch-port` and check your Elastic Search configuration in Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Test Configuration ? works for me but not tested locally

Comment: Try to use --elasticsearch-host=localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this one worked for me.

bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/local_m241/lcl_m241/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Vibhore_admin --admin-lastname=Jain_admin --admin-email=example@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200

A saw a video here and got some hint here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0013vPjz_xE ) to open elastic search in browser as http://localhost:9200/ which shows a JSON object lol. -  
 I appreciate Amit comment as it was also correct but I saw it after I already solved it. 
Thanks Amit anyways.